# Ask, how to use redirect without contition?

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-2, response.redirect, codeigniter-url

i have codes like this

```
    function download(){
            $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $dat = $this->mikland->gidiklanfoto($id);
            foreach ($dat as $item){
            $name = $item->foto; 
            $data = file_get_contents(base_url()."/uploads/".$name); // filenya
            force_download($name,$data); 
    }  
            redirect('cikland/viewiklan/'.$id);
   }
```

when the function are running, redirect cannot run., 
somebody can help??
i think is a simple thing but i dont know the trick., thank's before

Comment: I think you dont need to redirect in a download function. Just redirect in the next line after calling the download function. `redirect('cikland/viewiklan/'.$id, 'refresh');`

Comment: i have move the redirect code everywhere in function download ., but it didnt work,,
i tried to put the code after `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`  the redirect run but download not run

Answer (score 1):

At the end of `force_download()` there is an `exit()` statement, so no code after a forced download will run.

And you are trying to have several files downloaded at the same time - using some sort of multipart mime type, that might or might not work, but not in the given case, because CI's `force_download()` does not seem to support that.

An alternative to that would be creating a temporary archive file which contains all the files for download; please have a look at the official documentation on [compression and archives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) for that.

If you'd want to send a redirection header along with the file, you'd have to do it like this:

```
function download(){

    // add this somewhere befor the download
    header('Location: '.site_url('cikland/viewiklan/'.$id));

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $dat = $this->mikland->gidiklanfoto($id);

    // only first item is downloaded
    foreach ($dat as $item)
    {
        $name = $item->foto; 
        $data = file_get_contents(base_url()."/uploads/".$name); // filenya
        force_download($name,$data); 
   }  
}
```

But the question would remain how the browsers would deal with a redirect and content: most likely you would only get the redirect.

Comment: the browser cannot handle header()., it make a long url in the address bar.. 
i have move the redirect code everywhere in function download ., but it didnt work,,
i tried to put the code after `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`  the redirect run but download not run

Comment: ah sorry, CI's redirect would have prepended the uri with the site_url() base - I corrected the code accordingly. As for the redirect & download, as mentioned the combination likely will not work - as it's so specified (or common for browsers at least). You might try something with javascript to circumvent that

Answer (score 0):

You need load url helper.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

after

```
redirect("cikland/viewiklan/$id", 'refresh');
```

or

```
redirect("cikland/viewiklan/$id", 'location', 301);
```

Font: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: i have to set `$this->load->helper('url');` in the autoload file, i have tried to uses 'refresh' code but it doesnt work..
i have move the redirect code everywhere in function download ., but it didnt work,,
i tried to put the code after `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`  the redirect run but download not run

Answer (score 0):

`redirect()` method redirects to a URL. You need to pass it a full URL (as it uses the header() function which according to the RFC for HTTP1.1 requires a full URL.

so you need to hard code the full url like the given example - `redirect('http://www.yoursite.com/cikland/viewiklan/'.$id);`

Comment: No, not quite right. If `redirect($uri)` is not passed a string beginning with http or https it modifies $uri to be site_url($uri).

Comment: i have move the redirect code everywhere in function download ., but it didnt work,,
i tried to put the code after `$id = $this->uri->segment(3);`  the redirect run but download not run